# Reset subscription inside a timer

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

**Scenario:**

I have a api call (`this.service.checkStatus(this.movieForm.value.movie)`) which should be consumed at every 60 seconds. and between the 60 second, I need to show a 1 second counter (something like `x seconds until next call`). So I'm using two timer (`source$` & `source2$`). But the problem with the below code is `source2$` doesn't stops after a new api call, instead a new subscription is created for every 60 seconds. The old `source2$` subscription is still incrementing by 1 and the new one starts with 0 and making a mess. How can I fix this?

Below is my code.

**Code:**

```
source$ = timer(0, 60000); // every 60 seconds it will emit
source2$ = timer(0, 1000); // every 1 second it will emit
...
getStatus() {
    this.apiSubscription$ = this.source$.subscribe(() => {

      // I need to reset this timersubscription. so that the val always starts from 0

      this.timerSubscription$ = this.source2$.subscribe((val: number) => {
          this.timer = 60 - val;
          this.progress.nativeElement.style.width = (val / 60) * 100 + '%';
        });
      this.service.checkStatus(this.movieForm.value.movie)
        .pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe(res => {
          const response: any = res;
          if (!response.status) {
            // do stuff 1
          } else {
            // do stuff 2
            this.apiSubscription$.unsubscribe();
          }
        });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is part of why nested subscribes are an anti pattern and should be avoided... you want to be using the proper operators that handle subscribing and unsubscribing for you:

```
this.apiSubscription$ = source1$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => { // switchMap subscribes to new inner subscriptions and cancels previous ones
    const counter$ = source2$.pipe(
      tap(timer => { // tap lets you produce side effects
        this.timer = 60 - timer;
        this.progress.nativeElement.style.width = (timer / 60) * 100 + '%';
      })
    )
    const status$ = this.service.checkStatus(this.movieForm.value.movie).pipe(
      first(), // first is more semantic IMO
      tap(response => {
        if (!response.status) {
          // do stuff 1
        } else {
          // do stuff 2
        }
      })
    )
    return combineLatest(counter$, status$); // combine observables
  }),
   // takeWhile will end your subscription for you if the condition is false
  takeWhile(([timer, statusResponse]) => !!statusResponse.status)
).subscribe()
```

Comment: wow, this works fine without takeWhile. because i didn't declared statusResponse. so for now i'm unsubscribing inside the else part. and the ide says combineLatest is deprected. but still works. Is it ok to use `merge` instead of `combineLatest`?

Comment: CombineLatest is not deprecated. Merge would break the takeWhile, which should work fine and is the better method of unsubscribing.

Comment: In `takeWhile` may I know what should I give instead of statusResponse?

Comment: It will be whatever is returned from your checkStatus function